# Lets make this vba code more efficient

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to coding and have tried many recording and editing in VBA to learn somewhat what to do. I've also seached many sites to learn the basics of VBA. I'm finally finished with this VBA mini-program that I'm working on. Could you all take a look at it and tell me what I could change to make it more efficient or adaptable to other spreadsheets?

First of all, I copy and paste 2 worksheets from other workbooks into this new workbook and use this program on it. The first worksheet will have the most current information on all the products and new incoming products(without any comments). The second worksheet will basically be the worksheet I generated from the day before (with all the comments that other people have put onto it throughout the day). So basically it's an updating program. Most of the time, the second worksheet will go up to column R, but sometimes other people will delete a column and the last column used will be Q instead. So if someone could help in this it would be very much appreciated.

I usually start out entering in Due Date, Owner, and Location into the last 3 new columns. Then to make sure that they have the same font and spacing as the others, I change them to the same font accordingly. After that, I have to go through the 2nd worksheet, and copy the Due Date, Owner, and Location details and comments to the 1st worksheet in the corresponding cell that has the same serial number (usually in column F) and assembly number (usually in column E). There are a lot of the same assebly numbers but a few that are the same for serial numbers, that's why I did the If statements for the serial number first. After all the information is copied over, some of the comments are highlighted in various colors, so I have to make sure that the whole row has to be highlighted too.

After that, I change all of the body of the worksheet to a certain font, then autofit both columns and rows to make it look neater. Lastly, I order the 1st spreadsheet in decending order, then copy and paste it to a new spreadsheet so that it would be a regular spreadsheet without any macros on it.

I didn't know how to write some of the codes, so I just copied and pasted the recorded macros I tried before. All I did was change the range of it to cover the last entry at the least.

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim s1 As Worksheet
Dim s2 As Worksheet

Set s1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set s2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

a = s1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
b = s2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Cells(1, 19) = "Due Date"
Cells(1, 20) = "Owner"
Cells(1, 21) = "Location"

Rows("1:1").Select
With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .Size = 8
End With
Selection.Font.Bold = True
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U$500").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=WO", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=WR"
Rows("2:500").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U$500").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
    "Inventory"
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

Dim i As Integer
Dim ii As Integer

i = 2
ii = 2

For i = 2 To a
    For ii = 2 To b
        If s1.Cells(i, 6) = s2.Cells(ii, 6) Then
            If s1.Cells(i, 5) = s2.Cells(ii, 5) Then
                s2.Range(s2.Cells(ii, 18), s2.Cells(ii, 21)).Copy s1.Range(s1.Cells(i, 18), s1.Cells(i, 21))
                s1.Range(s1.Cells(i, 1), s1.Cells(i, 17)).Interior.ColorIndex = Cells(i, 18).Interior.ColorIndex
            End If
        End If
    Next ii
Next i

With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 8
End With

Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit

Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:U500")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: If the code works as intended, you may not be aware that [codereview.se] specializes in exactly this: turning *working code* into *great code*. Just saying ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always qualify your Ranges

```
Cells(1, 19)
```

Should have the worksheet qualifier

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 19)
```

This keeps proper references.

Also remove all `.Select` it slows it down:

This:

```
Rows("1:1").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        ...
```

Becomes:

```
With Worksheet("Sheet1").Rows("1:1").Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    ...
```

or you could:

```
With Worksheet("Sheet1").Rows("1:1")
    With .Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 8
        .Bold = True
    End with
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    With .Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End With
```

Comment: This is a nice and concise post Scott! I'll make sure to keep a link to it, as reminding folks to qualify ranges, and remove `.Select` is one of my most common comments. Kudos!

Comment: Eh, you're right. This isn't that great.  :P (kidding, of course)